# Cannot determine path to 'tools.jar' library for 18 (C:/Program Files/jdk-18.0.1.1)

Tags: java, kotlin, intellij-idea, compiler-errors, ide

i want to run my code in intellij ide (community edition)
and when i try to run it, i got this error

> Cannot determine path to 'tools.jar' library for 18 (C:/Program
> Files/jdk-18.0.1.1)

[This is the ScreenShot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P24Cq.png)

help me pls... i want to learn kotlin use intellij ide

[And this is my JAVA_HOME](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9MQC.png)

version ide : 2020.2
Thank you :)

Comment: Go to File -> Project Settings -> SDKs and check that "18" is properly configured.

Comment: @k314159 do you mean project structure? its already 18

Comment: Check the folder paths for "18" under "Platform Settings"

Comment: @k314159 and then?

Comment: Check that the folders and files named under "18" (in particular, those in the Classpath tab) actually exist on your machine.

Answer (score 30):

The problem is with version of JDK you are using. The Intellij version 2020.2 supports only upto  JDK 14. So either you have to lower the JDK version to 14 or update the IntelliJ to a newer version like 2021.

Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/supported-java-versions.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same error recently (Nov 2022)

```
Error:Cannot determine path to 'tools.jar' library for 17 (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.5)
```

when using IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1.4 with JDK 17.0.5. Issue is resolved by switching to open JDK amazon-corretto-11, you can download it from here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-11-ug/downloads-list.html

Amazon Corretto is a no-cost, multiplatform, production-ready distribution of the Open Java Development Kit (OpenJDK). Corretto comes with long-term support that includes performance enhancements and security fixes.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the same problem this morning, i had tried many approaches like upgrading to latest JDK and downgrading to older JDKs. None of them helped me. Finally I updated to IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.3 (Community Edition), and things started working smoothly.